How to get unique browser binary path identification from PHP?
In a PHP script I want to get a unique browser ID, but not so unique as the user agent ($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]) as the UA changes with every version. I tried removing all numerals in the UA string to evade version dependency, but that has as a side effect that 'cloned' browsers like Brave (a Chrome clone) has the same user agent as Chrome itself when omitting digits in the UA string.
I thought that using the browser binary (i.e. like /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resouces/MacOS/Firefox or /usr/bin/firefox) is unique per browser and version independant. But how can I achieve this path (or other unique ID) ?
EDIT: The issue is that I want to get a unique browser ID which is independant on version number but cloned browsers shoud differ from original. So Firefox vs Waterfox or Chrome vs Brave should differ, but Firefox 132 should return the same as Firefox 130.

You can't get the browser executable path.

What do you want to use this unique browser id for? You told us the method you think you can solve your problem with, but you didn't say anything about the problem you're actually trying to tackle.

See the EDIT, I hope is is more clear.

You still didn't say why you need it.

The reason I ask for the "why?" is that there may be another solution to the problem you're trying to tackle which you haven't thought of. It now sounds like you want to identify the browser, for some reason. But why? To see what features it will support? Which features?

I agree. In most cases as server side script such as php should not need to know or care what software an incoming request came from. To php it's just a http request containing some data. The source is usually irrelevant. Why do you need this, and also why is the user-agent insufficient?

I agree that the "why" is not well articulated here. You've explained what you want and why your solution doesn't work. However, you have not articulated the underlying problem you are solving. Why are you targeting browsers? You might come up with a clever solution to "identifying browsers" and it might be a really bad way to solve whatever problem you're trying to solve.

A good example would be if you were checking the HTTP_USER_AGENT for some sort of security reason. Since HTTP_USER_AGENT can be spoofed, you'd have "solved the problem of identifying the brand of browser" while failing to solve the security problem. You'll have created a "really good solution to a different problem".
Defining your "why" is the first step to becoming effective, instead of merely efficient.

I think filtering the HTTP_USER_AGENT string is the best solution. It would allow you to identify the browser without capturing the version number. However, the downside is, you may end up with "Unknown" browsers. You could of course, store this information, and find a way to filter the string. Another downside is that HTTP_USER_AGENT can be spoofed (but that's not a downside of the code, just your chosen solution).
Because HTTP_USER_AGENT strings share common keywords, the order in which you filter the string is important.
Here is an example of how you might achieve it (I used a switch statement because it made it easier to see how the solution is being devised).
(In the code below, we check to see if a keyword known to be in the HTTP_USER_AGENT string is found. If it is not, we move to the next possibility. Finally, if we haven't found a match, we "dump" it into an Unknown category).
<?php
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

switch (true) {
    // Check for Samsung Internet. I think it might include 'Chrome' so check it early
    case (strpos($userAgent, 'SamsungBrowser') !== false):
        $browser = 'Samsung Internet';
        break;

    // Brave needs to be checked before Google Chrome
    case (strpos($userAgent, 'Brave') !== false):
        $browser = 'Brave';
        break;

    // Opera also includes 'Chrome'
    case (strpos($userAgent, 'OPR') !== false):
        $browser = 'Opera';
        break;

    // Microsoft Edge includes 'Chrome'
    case (strpos($userAgent, 'Edg') !== false):
        $browser = 'Edge';
        break;

    // QQ Browser also includes 'Chrome'
    case (strpos($userAgent, 'QQBrowser') !== false):
        $browser = 'QQ Browser';
        break;

    // UC Browser also includes 'Chrome'
    case (strpos($userAgent, 'UCBrowser') !== false):
        $browser = 'UC Browser';
        break;

    // Android browser
    case (strpos($userAgent, 'Android')):
        $browser = 'Android Browser';
        break;


    // Now we can check for Google Chrome
    case (strpos($userAgent, 'Chrome') !== false):
        $browser = 'Chrome';
        break;

    // Firefox is easy :)
    case (strpos($userAgent, 'Firefox') !== false):
        $browser = 'Firefox';
        break;

    // Safari must be after Chrome because Chrome includes 'Safari'
    // Here a double-check that it doesn't include 'Chrome'
    case (strpos($userAgent, 'Safari') !== false && strpos($userAgent, 'Chrome') === false):
        $browser = 'Safari';
        break;

    // Unknown
    default:
        $browser = 'Unknown';
        break;
}

echo "The browser being used is: " . $browser;
?>

The downside to a solution like this is that you might have a bucket of unknowns. However, these are the top 10 browsers identified by https://gs.statcounter.com/. They represent 98+% of the Global Market.
Note: I have not tested the filter because I don't have these 10 browsers installed. You might want to verify the filter. At the very least, you will want to double-check the HTTP_USER_AGENT strings are accurate for the browsers I've listed above. You might also want to target more browsers (e.g. gaming console browsers) depending on your audience.

What a weird use of a switch ()  statement. Why not define an ordered array with all the browser names and then simply check all of those against the user agent in a loop? The code would execute the same while needing one third of the code.

You could solve this in many ways -- this "weird" use of a switch statement is because it was the easiest way to illustrate what is going on.
